# Why is it called response file

Tags: msbuild

MBuild can use response files to save and run commands. But why is it called response file? What is it responding to?

(Also in an MsBuild file the task elements are called Target. What is 'target'  refering too?)

Comment: note that this has nothing to do with asp.net. You could remove that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A target represents a collection of things you want to do. In an msbuild file, it is represented by an xml element that can have various child xml elements called tasks. 
Conceptually it looks like this:

```
    <Target Name="Foo">
        <Task />
        <AnotherTask />
    </Target>
```

The target you want to execute can be passed in as a command line parameter to msbuild. There are other ways to execute the target of your choice, but you will need to read the docs for that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019

In other build systems, a target can be called a goal.

Note:
Some build systems use a very rigid convention, where files have to be in certain places. MSBuild is not like that. It relies on configuration, where you can configure it any way you like. The only convention's really are the xml syntax and schema that you have to follow.

As for the response file name. Who knows and who cares anyways? It's just an extra place to put more command line parameters. I don't rely on it, and neither should you. If you know what you are doing you can stick all that stuff in a proper msbuild xml file and just invoke `msbuild` to kick off a build.